# Why Orchard doesn't have model view controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, modular-design, plugin-architecture, clean-architecture

I am working with orchard. writing such a project is my dream!.. so i started a research a bout that. which interested me about orchard, is while orchard is mvc project but why it doesn't have any **model** , **view** and **controller** in his web layer solution?  does it use  `CleanArchitecture` or some specific architecture like [this](http://www.matthewrenze.com/articles/clean-architecture-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) ?

i tried to know about this case in orchards documents but i didn't find any description about it.

Comment: Orhcard uses `model`, `view` and `controller`, but it builds the model and views dynamically based on composition

Comment: can you give me a little more information or some resource about composition or what i must know about? @devqon

Comment: I suggest to read some [documentation of its architecture](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/How-Orchard-works/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, Orchard being an MVC based project, it intrinsically does have *models*, *views* and *controllers*. But it provides much more than that.

The key thing to understand, in my mind, is that at the very core, requests are handled by a given controller, which builds a model, and returns a view that uses this model. What Orchard adds to that is how it builds up a particular model, and how it selects the view to display that model.

Consider requesting a content item by navigating to, say, a content item with alias "/about".

What happens is that the ASP.NET routing will kick in, which has been configured to match against aliases of all content items. The route for "/about" will be found, which is handled by the *ItemController* of the Contents module (modules in Orchard are conceptually the same as MVC areas). The *ItemController* will build a dynamic model for the requested content item, which is called a *shape*. The shape is an instance of the *Shape* class, which contains metadata about the shape, such as the name of the shape. Based on this information, Orchard leverages the view engine to select the appropriate Razor *view* to render the shape object.

So you see, all of the basic MVC stuff comes into play. Orchard simply adds a powerful infrastructure on top of it to provide an advanced and flexible rendering system, like turning content items into shapes, which are then turned into HTML via the view engine. But at the end of the day, it's primarily about controllers creating models used by views.